# Constraints like @Assert\NotBlank() annotation for entities does not work in unit test which gives semantical or auto loaded error

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, autoload

When I run the Unit test it gives the following error for the constraints

**[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property AppBundle\Entity\User::$username does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.**

Here is my entity

**User.class**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;


/**
 * Class User
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /** @var double
     *  @ORM\Column(type="bigint", nullable=false)
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullname", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $fullname;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="createdat", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $createdat;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="modifiedat", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected  $modifiedat;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default" = 1}, nullable=false)
     */
    private $isactive = true;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Now we tell doctrine that before we persist or update we call the updatedTimestamps() function.
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        $this->setModifiedat(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

        if($this->getCreatedat() == null)
        {
            $this->setCreatedat(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        }
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return '';
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isactive;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isactive
        ));
    }


    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isactive
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set isactive
     *
     * @param boolean $isactive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsactive($isactive)
    {
        $this->isactive = $isactive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isactive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsactive()
    {
        return $this->isactive;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }



    /**
     * Set fullname
     *
     * @param string $fullname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFullname($fullname)
    {
        $this->fullname = $fullname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullname()
    {
        return $this->fullname;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdat
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdat
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreatedat($createdat)
    {
        $this->createdat = $createdat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdat
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedat()
    {
        return $this->createdat;
    }

    /**
     * Set modifiedat
     *
     * @param \DateTime $modifiedat
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setModifiedat($modifiedat)
    {
        $this->modifiedat = $modifiedat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modifiedat
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getModifiedat()
    {
        return $this->modifiedat;
    }

    /**
     * The __toString method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is converted to a string.
     *
     * @return string
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring
     */
    function __toString()
    {
        return "id: ". $this->id ."  email: ". $this->username . "  fullname: ". $this->fullname . "  isactive: ". $this->isactive .
        "  createdat: ". $this->createdat->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."  updatedat: ". $this->modifiedat->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

This is my Unit Test classes:

**TestBase.class**

```
namespace tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use AppKernel;

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("../../../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php");
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php";


class TestBase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    protected $application;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var \AppKernel
     */
    protected $kernel;

    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    protected $container;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->kernel = new AppKernel("test", true);
        $this->kernel->boot();
        $this->application = new Application($this->kernel);
        $this->application->setAutoExit(false);

        // Store the container and the entity manager in test case properties
        $this->container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
        $this->entityManager = $this->container->get("doctrine")->getManager();

        if(is_null($this->entityManager)){
            print("upssss entitiy manager is null :(");
        }

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        // Shutdown the kernel.
        $this->kernel->shutdown();

        parent::tearDown();
    }

}
```

And here I test my User class just printing the database..

**UserTest.class**

```
namespace tests\AppBundle\Controller;

require_once ("TestBase.php");

class UserTest extends TestBase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    //generic method to list the users
    public function listUsers($users ){
        echo EOL, EOL;
        foreach($users as $user){
            echo $user, EOL;
        }
        echo EOL, EOL;
    }

    public function testListUsers(){

        $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();
        $this->assertGreaterThan(1, count($users));
        $this->listUsers($users);
    }
}
```

By the way it works when I don't use @Assert\NotBlank()
So from code-wise there is no problem at all... I guess it is just about autoloading when unit testing..

I really got stuck for 2 weeks with that..

Comment: Symfony version used? PS: use NotNull instead of NotBlank.

Comment: @gp_sflover Symfony 3.05 and none of the Assert constraints work as annotation including NotNull, I tried almost all of them and it seems the Assertions can't be autoloaded in unit testing.. 

There is no problem when I use it through Controllers, my only concern is to use it in Unit Test as well..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer..

When I changed ***test*** to ***dev*** in AppKernel it worked

old one was this:

```
$this->kernel = new AppKernel("test", true);
```

solution

```
$this->kernel = new AppKernel("dev", true);
```

I didn't change my AppKernel.php though

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is why did that change fix the issue... I cant think of why that would have helped.